# Information Leakage Due to Fault Propagation in XOR gates

Tags: fault-attack

In the concept of Automatic Test Pattern Generation (ATPG), two events are required to perform in sequence: **Fault Activation** and **Fault Propagation**.
[image]
In the case of a linear 2-input XOR gate, without loss of generality, we consider a stuck-at-0 fault at the input register *a*, while the input register *b* may take values independently. In order to activate the fault at *a*, one must set *a* = 1. The next step is to propagate the fault at the output. One may observe that setting the input *b* to either 0 or 1 will expose the fault at *a* to the output *o*.
In continuation of article, he says with assuming the fault to be stuck-at-0, just by observing whether the output is faulty Adversary can determine the value of a. More precisely, if the output is fault-free *a* = 0 and *a* = 1, otherwise.
In continuation of article, he says with assuming the fault to be stuck-at-0, just by observing whether the output is faulty Adversary can determine the value of *a*. More precisely, if the output is fault-free *a* = 0 and *a* = 1, otherwise.
I am confused at this point, when the type of fault is stuck-at-0 how the value of *a* is equal to 0 in the case of "fault-free"? Have I misunderstood the concept?